# Gmake macro expansion: macro calls macro with variable in arguments

Tags: make, macro

In the following makeffile one macro process it's arguments to call another macro. I expect that makefile below will generate two targets and correct list of the targets in $TARGETS. But in fact it only generates one target with correct list. How to do such macro call in correct way?

```
all: $TARGETS
define f2
.PHONY: target$(1)
target$(1):
    echo "We are in $(1)"
TARGETS+=target$(1)
endef

define f1
VAR$(1)=ValueWith$(1)
$(eval $(call f2,$$(VAR$(1))))
endef

$(eval $(call f1,CallOne))
$(eval $(call f1,CallTwo))

$(warning Warning: $(TARGETS))
```

output of make:

```
test.mk:16: warning: overriding recipe for target `target'
test.mk:15: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `target'
test.mk:18: Warning: targetValueWithCallOne targetValueWithCallTwo
gmake: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add some more debugging code.

```
all: $TARGETS
define f2
$$(info f2 called on $(1))
.PHONY: target$(1)
target$(1):
    echo "We are in $(1)"
TARGETS+=target$(1)
endef

define f1
VAR$(1)=ValueWith$(1)
$(info too early: VAR$(1) is $$(VAR$(1)))
$$(info right time: VAR$(1) is $$(VAR$(1)))
$(eval $(call f2,$(VAR$(1))))
endef

$(eval $(call f1,CallOne))
$(eval $(call f1,CallTwo))

$(warning Warning: $(TARGETS))
```

Output:

```
too early: VARCallOne is $(VARCallOne)
f2 called on 
right time: VARCallOne is ValueWithCallOne
too early: VARCallTwo is $(VARCallTwo)
f2 called on 
debug.mk:18: warning: overriding commands for target `target'
debug.mk:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `target'
right time: VARCallTwo is ValueWithCallTwo
debug.mk:20: Warning: target target
make: *** No rule to make target `ARGETS', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

The problem is that the `eval` call is made before the definition of `VAR…`, at the time the function `f1` is expanded, instead of at the time the result of that expansion is processed. You need to delay the `eval`.

Also there is a typo in line 1; if you fix it, you'll find that the target `all` builds nothing since `TARGETS` is not defined at the time it's used. You need to declare the dependencies later.

```
all:  # default target, declare it first

define f2
.PHONY: target$(1)
target$(1):
        echo "We are in $(1)"
TARGETS+=target$(1)
endef

define f1
VAR$(1)=ValueWith$(1)
$$(eval $$(call f2,$$(VAR$(1))))
endef

$(eval $(call f1,CallOne))
$(eval $(call f1,CallTwo))

$(warning Warning: $(TARGETS))
all: $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: Thank you. I learnt a lot from your explanation and it indeed answers my question.